# Unable to install grunt in Windows 11 npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, node-modules, npm-install

OS: Windows 11
Node: 16

I am trying to install grunt-cli globally in Windows 11. I tried following command:

```
npm i grunt-cli -g
```

and getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-20T07_00_36_434Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried setting the following in npm configuration:

```
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Validated using

```
npm config get registry
```

I am not sure what could be causing this issue, any suggestions on how to address this?